# How can I record sound in Mac OS?

Tags: audio

Is there any simple application (or built-in in Mac OS) that allows me to record sound on a Mac? I'm referring not only to voice input through the mic, but also to sounds issued by the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Audio Hijack](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) and [WireTap Studio](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/wiretap/) are both application suites for recording audio from any input, include the system audio. They're not fee, but their trials might suffice.

A simpler solution would be [SoundFlower](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14067/soundflower/) which acts like an output to which system audio can be sent, then used as an input source in any audio recording program, even quicktime. If you want to be able to hear sound from your speakers/headphones, you'll need to run the sound flower bed app, which takes sound flower's audio coming in from your system, and forwards it to your speakers/headphones while still being able to use it.

Comment: +1 for Audio Hijack Pro. Although it isn't free, it is worth it!

Comment: I have mixed views of it, it's too full blown for most uses which just require basic system sound input, an area in which SoundFlower excels

Comment: Yes, but the amount of control Audio Hijack gives you is nice for a power user like me. :-)

Comment: Well yes, i enjoy that too, but often times it's overkill. I usually use sound flower in addition to an aggregate midi device to be able to voice chat in Skype with system sound being channelled.

Comment: Ah. SoundFlower is good too...I should use it more often, as it is pretty powerful.

Comment: It's the system integration that i enjoy about it, i like how it can be used in any place where sound in/outputs can be used

Comment: Totally agree!!

Answer (score 2):

You want [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/). Records system audio, from long time quality Mac developer, [Rogue Amoeba](http://www.rogueamoeba.com).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the one XAleXOwnZX gave, it just has a link for Audacity and a tutorial.

If you want to do it for free you can download Audacity and Soundflower (if you have a mac) and record the sound straight off your sound card.

Audacity: http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/

Soundflowerbed: http://cycling74.com/downloads/

Tutorial: [http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/User:BillWharrie/Using_Soundflower_to_record_streaming_audio](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/User%3aBillWharrie/Using_Soundflower_to_record_streaming_audio)